# Seeking Guidance on PHPStan Configuration for Legacy Code Migration - "Variable $... might not be defined"

Tags: php, upgrade, php-8, legacy-code, phpstan

I am currently in the process of migrating a large, super-legacy codebase to PHP 8.x, and I am utilizing PHPStan to identify potential issues. However, I have encountered a challenge related to the inclusion of files using global variables, which PHPStan struggles to resolve.

The problematic code includes file inclusions with global variables using a structure like `include(magicLogic());`, leading to over 10,000 error messages such as "Variable $myvar might not be defined."

I am aware that adding `/** @var mixed myvar */` in the file header resolves the issue. However, dealing with over 100 such scripts and more than a thousand reported variables makes this approach impractical.

I am also aware that I can disable the whole error message using `ignoreErrors` section in `phpstan.neon`. Which I would prefer to avoid to don't miss real undefined variables.

To address this, I have compiled a list of variables in a globals.stub.php file, intending to point PHPStan to it from the `phpstan.neon` configuration. Unfortunately, my attempts have not been successful.

Here's an overview of my configuration:

`phpstan.neon`:

```
parameters:
    level: 2
    paths:
        - %rootDir%/../../../

    scanFiles:
        - globals.stub.php
    
    stubFiles:
        - globals.stub.php

    bootstrapFiles:
        - globals.stub.php

    excludePaths:
        - vendor
```

`test.php`:

```php
<?php
echo $myvar;
?>
```

`globals.stub.php`:

```php
<?php
global $myvar;
/** @var string $myvar */
$myvar = 'Hello World!';
$GLOBALS['myvar'] = $myvar;
?>
```

Despite these efforts, the error persists when running PHPStan:

```sql
Note: Using configuration file ./phpstan.neon.
 1/1 [▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓] 100%

 ------ --------------------------------------- 
  Line   test.php                               
 ------ --------------------------------------- 
  4      Variable $myvar might not be defined.  
 ------ ---------------------------------------
```

It's important to note that:

- Modifying the PHP files being checked is not an option.
- Manually adding PHPStan comments to hundreds of files is impractical.
- My job is to find the easiest and fastest way how to run the scripts on PHP8.
- The same issue is with constants.

I am seeking a solution to incorporate the list of variables into a stub file and have PHPStan recognize it.